# Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null build failed

Tags: flutter

I have updated to the latest flutter update. When I want to start the project, it returns an error. The project depends on several repositories and I don't know if that is why. I have tried multiple solutions but they do not solve the error. Hope someone can help me. thanks.

Compiler message:

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mvvm-0.1.7/lib/view_context_helpers/logical.dart:151:25: Error: The function expression type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Null, Widget) Function(TValue)' isn't of expected type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, TValue, Widget) Function(TValue)'.

 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Change the type of the function expression or the context in which it is used.
              selector: (TValue value) =>
                        ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 31s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Strange, it's very frustrating when this happen, I0m sure you tried flutter clean, an close an open the project from fresh... In some bad cases the best solution I found is to create a new project and copy there my lib, and update the pubspec.yaml to meet the requirements. Some times is one of the dependencies, the best is to coment one by one to see if any is responsible for the crash, hope you solve it.

Comment: change compileSdkVersion to 28 in android app-level build.gradle file

Comment: Already level 28. It did not work. I created a new project. I moved the lib file, but it didn't work.

Comment: try `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` then `dart fix --apply`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i found this issue  [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42356) TL:DR here is a summary

It looks like your local engine build flutter/engine and framework + tool flutter/flutter are out of sync: You're using an engine from when after `SemanticsFlag.isLink` was added, but a framework/tool from before it rolled into the framework.

You need to ensure that you're using compatible engines and frameworks. In this case, you need to either update flutter/flutter to a newer version or roll back flutter/engine to an older version.[42356](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42356)

Comment: Thank you. This solves my problem. I hope the problem will disappear in the future.

Comment: Did u downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

```html
Solution 1
1.Ensure compatible engines and frameworks. 
2.Update flutter or install flutter to a newer version, 

still issue persists,  Roll back flutter or engine to an older version.

Best solution to fix by time saving but not preferable, please follow 

Solution 2
1. Download latest version flutter sdk and setup.
2. Fix it by creating a new project and copying the code from the old one.
```

For more details refer the below link

http://codekhichdi.com/flutter/target-kernel_snapshot-failed-exception-errors-during-snapshot-creation-null

Answer (score 0):

```dart
import 'package:food_ecommerce/pages/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:food_ecommerce/pages/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/widgets.dart';
```

Delete such headers in my case I delete these two headers and my program runs.

Answer (score -1):

If upgrade/downgrade as mentioned above still doesn't fix the issue, perhaps the flutter channel is in master or else. Change the channel to 'stable' with:

```
flutter channel stable
```

After changing the channel, upgrade it:

```
flutter upgrade
```

reopen the editor/ide to make sure it's using the new engine, and then run your project.

This method worked for me.