# Flutter gives me error everytime i run any app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I recently installed flutter but whenever i run any flutter app it shows this error -

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/ashvinbhagat/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
Could not compile script '/Users/ashvinbhagat/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  script '/Users/ashvinbhagat/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle': 1: expecting EOF, found ':' @ line 1, column 32.
     Script started on Wed Apr 29 18:07:22 2020
                                    ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How should i fix it, it is not a problem with my app, it is problem with flutter

Comment: have you looked upon this [question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369091/target-kernel-snapshot-failed-exception-errors-during-snapshot-creation-null) It might help you.

Comment: no it didn't worked.

Comment: change the flutter version and create a new project see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tries i solved the issue with changing cached_network_image

`cached_network_image: ^2.1.0+1`