# the vs code give me this error when i run flutter project (it was run i did many projects)

Tags: flutter

i get this error when i run the project

```
} else phase if (owner!._debugStateLocked) {
             ^^^^^
/C:/Users/New%201000%20Mezza/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:5210:14: Error: The getter 'phase' isn't defined for the class 'Element'.
 - 'Element' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/Users/New%201000%20Mezza/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'phase'.
      } else phase if (owner!._debugStateLocked) {
             ^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\New 1000 Mezza\Downloads\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

solve of this problem please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe this answers your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/59372800/6193799